# Android backstack with drawer menu

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

I have an application with a single Activity that uses a menu drawer for navigation. Every time an item in the menu drawer is clicked I replace the fragment showing with a new one and add it to the backstack. Say I have 4 menu items, A B C D E, with their coresponing fragments. If the user opens A it ends up in the backstack, if the user then clicks B and then A again the backstack looks like this: A --> B --> A, and fragment A is visible.

When the user now navigates back using the back button, first fragment B will show. If the user navigates back again he will see fragment A again (which he just saw before seeing B). In an Activity backstack the user would go from B out of the app and not to A again, because thats where he just came from.

How can I remove all existing backstack entries of a fragment in the backstack when it is added? I only want to have maximum one entry of each fragment in the backstack att al time.

Please feel free to ask if you dont get what I mean.

Comment: hello, did you figure it out ? I am facing the same problem now :(

Comment: I just ended up doing it all manually, keeping track of the stack myself at all time.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code :-

```
        Fragment newFragment;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        newFragment = new MyFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

If you mentioned following line in your code then remove this:-

```
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```